# Why is my SSRS report is splitting Grouped data into two Groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have an existing SSRS report which sometimes splits a group into two rows with part of the groups summary in one group row and the remainder in another. I can run the report several times (even different instances at the same time) and get different results; sometimes the group is in one row sometimes it is split into two rows. It is not double counting data, the data is splitting between the two groups.

I have redeployed the report and reset the subscriptions. Checked code to ensure the definition of the column for the group is consistent.

Comment: can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is no problem with the code, which always returns the required result when run in Management Studio... Also the SSRS report is sometimes as expected just intermittently an extra row appears in a table which splits a group into two groups. The group is determined by a case statement which is classifying the data with the same text in the group column it is just splitting when the report is rendering.

Comment: While the people requesting reproducible examples usually don't know what you (or they) are talking about, it would be helpful to show this issue - a screenshot of the data when split and not split and a pic of your design view with the table selected so the grouping lines show on the left (parenthesis-looking grouping or hamburger-menu-looking detail lines) of the table.